# Dynamically created DOM can't hold up in cache

Tags: java, ajax, dom, jakarta-ee

Hi I am building div content with AJAX call, but when I make call to any page from loaded page, if there is any exception the content loaded from AJAX call is not there in previous page. Is there any way to stop happening that?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the development environment, language, etc.

Comment: Please rephrase, preferably using a list of clear steps that are taken. For example, it's not clear what you mean by "make a call to any page" and "previous page".

Comment: Environment: j2ee, JQuery, AJAX
Steps:
1. on clicking on a button on a browser makes a AJAX call for html content
2. build DOM using Jquery object and append the same to a DIV
3. Now clicking on a button on newly build DOM makes a call to a servlet, which throws exception
4. If you click on Back button in Browser on getting exception, there was no content loaded from AJAX in the DIV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ajax vs Back button**

If I understand well you are pressing the browser back button.

If you don't manage the history of the browser, it will break Ajax. The browser simply goes to the last location loaded, no ajax involved. If you did 3 ajax calls/loads in the last page, back button will ignore this because *it's just javascript in the page* and it will go back... very back.

**What you can do**

There are things you can do to preserve the back semantics in your ajax app but I don't know how you do it with jquery. Maybe it has tools for that. I know something about GWT that has history managing. But it's another framework...

Answer (score 0):

See the History plugin.  Highly recommended for this purpose.